# :last-child in ng-repeat not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I was using angular's ng-repeat to print a div multiple times. But the styling seem to get a little wrong with the last child. I need to provide specific styling to the last-child of the ng-repeat's element. Here is what I was doing:

```css
.link-tickets div:last-child{
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="medium-4 column no-pad-left link-tickets" ng-repeat="ticket_data in acct_details.tickets">
  <p><a href="#details/{{acct_details.client_id}}/ticket/{{ticket_data.ticket_id}}"><strong class="bold-color">{{acct_details.client_name}}</strong></a>
                            <br>{{available_stages[ticket_data.stage_id].stage_name}}
                            <br>{{ticket_data.created_at | format | date}}</p>
                        </div>
```

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: i thing you want to this .link-tickets:last-child{
 float:left;
}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use the special variable `$last` (or `$first`) which is available inside the `ng-repeat` loop.

`$last` has value true when the current element is the last one in the array. `$first` works the same but for the first element :)

Then you can use it inside `ng-class` like this

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-class="{'last-item': $last}">
</ul>
```

and then define `.last-item` css class

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I got the question wrong. I figured it out myself.

```css
.medium-4.column.no-pad-left.link-tickets.ng-scope {
  float: left;
}
```

this is totally working out.